# Performance overhead of large class size in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, class

Quite an academic question this - I've had it remarked that a class I've written in a WCF service is very long (~3000 lines) and it should be broken down into smaller classes.

The scope of the service has grown over time and the methods contained contain many similar functions hence me not creating multiple smaller classes up until now so I've no problem with doing so (other than the time it'll take to do so!), but it got me thinking - is there a significant performance overhead in using a single large class instead of multiple smaller classes? If so, why?

Comment: That really depends on how it's used and what it does... and how it's written.  My guess is there should be less worry about performance overhead than memory overhead, though.

Comment: "is there a significant performance overhead in using a single large class instead of multiple smaller classes?" -**No** **BUT...It is simply poor design.  Sometimes you cannot avoid it but it sounds like in this case you can.**

Comment: Performance, in what respect, serialization? In that case, perhaps, if by violating single-responsibility you are forcing unnecessary information to be sent. Mainly, the concern is maintainability.

Comment: I agree with all the comments here, it was borne of some rapid requirements needing to be implemented and I am in the process of refactoring the class right now into a more manageable and elegant set of smaller classes, I was simply intrigued to find out what the overall likelihood of performance gain there'd be. Cheers!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It won't make any noticeable difference. Before even thinking about such extreme micro-optimization, you should think about maintainability, which is quite endangered with a class of about 3000 LOC.

Write your code first such that it is correct and maintainable. Only if you then really run into performance problems, you should first profile your application before making any decisions about optimizations. Usually performance bottlenecks will be found somewhere else (lack of parallelization, bad algorithms etc.).

Comment: Very true indeed - with multiple developers working on the class I'm shocked it's gotten so big so quickly. We've load-tested the service and it's performing very well indeed, hence my interest in finding out if there would be a gain from that perspective, but the manageability would indeed increase through refactoring. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

No, having one large class should not affect performance. Splitting a large class into smaller classes could even *reduce* performance as you will have more redirections. However, the impact is negligible in almost all cases.

The purpose of splitting a class into smaller parts is not to improve performance but to make it easier to read, modify and maintain the code. But this alone is enough reason to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Performance considerations are the last of your worries when it comes to the decision to add a handful of well designed classes over a single source file. Think more of:

- Maintainability... It's hard to make point fixes in so much code.
- Readability... If a you have to page up and down like a fiend to
  get anywhere, it's not readable.
- Reusability... No decomposition
  makes things difficult to reuse.
- Cohesion... If you're doing too
  many things in a single class, it's probably not cohesive in any way.
- Testability... Good luck unit testing a 3,000 LoC bunch of
  spaghetti code to any sensible level of coverage.

I could go on, but the mentality of large single source files seems to hark back to the VB/Procedureal programing era. Nowadays, I start to get the fear if a method has a cyclomatic complexity of more than 15 and a class has more than a couple of hundred lines in it.

Usually I find that if I refactor one of these 10k line of code behemoths, the sum total of the lines of code of the new classes ends up being 40% of the original if not less. More classes and decomposition (within reason) lead to less code. Counterintuitive at first, but it really works.

Comment: Thankfully we've used regions to logically split the code and reduce the page up/down scenario, I'm now refactoring it into separate classes using those regions as a base - thanks!

Comment: Although I love regions after a fashion, the criticism has been levelled at Microsoft that they cause more problems than they solve by "hiding the issue" of code bloat.

Comment: I like regions but only to seperate out my class by constructors, dependencies, configurations, state, and methods.  It helps me keep these conceptual properties and methods seperate.

Comment: If you need regions so you can "hide" parts of the code to make it more readable the class is already too big, IMHO. Don't hide the ugly, fix it!

Answer (score 3):

The real issue is not performance overhead. The overhead is in maintainability and reuse. You may have hard of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles of Object Oriented design, a number of which imply smaller classes are better. In particular, I'd look at the Single Responsibility Principle, the Open/Closed Principle and the Liskov Substitution Principle, and... actually, come to think of it they all pretty much imply smaller classes are better, albeit indirectly.

This stuff is not easy to 'get'. If you've been programming with an OO language a while you look at SOLID and it suddenly makes so much sense. But until those lightbulbs come on it can seem a bit obscure.

On a far simpler note, having several classes, with one file per class, each one sensibly named to describe the behaviour, where each class has a single job, has to be easier to manage from a pure sanity perspective than a long page of 3,000 lines.

And then consider if one part of your 3,000 line class might be useful in another part of your program... putting that functionality in a dedicated class is an excellent way of encapsulating it for reuse.

In essence, as I write, I'm finding I'm just teasing out aspects of SOLID anyway. You'd probably be best to read [straight from the horses mouth on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there are performance issues, but rather maintenance a readability issues. It's far more easier to modify more classes that each perform its purpose than to work with a single monstrous class. That's just ridiculous. You're breaking all OOP principles by doing so.

> hence me not creating multiple smaller classes up until now so I've no
>   problem with doing so

Precisely the case I've been warning of multiple times at SO already... People are afraid of premature optimization, but they are not afraid of writing a bad code with an idea like "I'll fix it later when it becomes an issue". Let me tell you something - 3000+ LOC class IS already an issue, no matter the performance impacts, if any.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how class is used and how often is instantiated. When class is instantiated once, e.g. contract service class, than performance overhead typical is not significant.

When class will be instantiated often, than it could reduce performance.

**But in this case think not about performance, think about it design.** Better to think about support and further development and testability. Classes of 3K LOC are huge and typically books of anti-patterns. Such classes are leading to code duplication and bugs, further development will be painful and causes already fixed bugs appear again and again, code is fragile.

**So class definitely should be refactored.**